# Using AMP script and javascript

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

I have a js function that returns a value I extracted from the HTML DOM. Now I want to send the data to AMPscript and store in a variable. Can it be done in that way? Or is there a better way?

Also, is there any way to get the value of a checkbox, i.e. clicked or not  through AMPscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the server-side javascript function `Variable.SetValue()` to pass your js variable value to an AMPscript variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var variableToPass = 'test'
Variable.SetValue("myVariable",variableToPass);

</script>

%%=v(@myVariable)=%%
```

`@myVariable` should resolve to "test"

To get the value of checkboxes, you can use the `RequestParameter()` AMPscript function, using the `name` value of your checkbox.

[Variable.SetValue()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesVariableSetValue.htm)

[RequestParameter()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)

Comment: OP is mentioning DOM and JS, meaning this is most probably a question in the context of client side and not server side JavaScript